# Mininet unable to receive packets

Tags: python, mininet

I'm trying to create UDP connection within host1 and host2. On the host1 it successfully sent 10 packets but on host2 it does not receive any data packet from host1. Is there any wrong configuration on my code that make host2 cannot receive packet from host1

Heres my code below

```
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.link import TCLink
import random
import re

def simulate_packet_loss():
    # Create Mininet network
    net = Mininet()

    # Add hosts and switches
    host1 = net.addHost('h1', ip='10.0.0.1/24')
    host2 = net.addHost('h2', ip='10.0.0.2/24')
    switch = net.addSwitch('s1')

    # Add links between hosts and switch with manipulated bandwidth
    bandwidth = random.randint(1, 10)  # Manipulated bandwidth in Mbps
    loss_percentage = random.randint(1, 10)  # Desired packet loss percentage
    link1 = net.addLink(host1, switch, cls=TCLink, bw=bandwidth, loss=loss_percentage)
    link2 = net.addLink(host2, switch, cls=TCLink, bw=bandwidth, loss=loss_percentage)

    # Start the network
    net.start()

    # Start UDP server on host2 to receive packets
    udp_server_script = """
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('10.0.0.2', 5000))
packets_received = 0
output_file = open('/tmp/output.txt', 'w')
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    packets_received += 1
    print('Received packet:', data)
    output_file.write('Received packet: ' + data.decode('utf-8') + '\\n')
    output_file.flush()
output_file.close()
"""
    with open('/tmp/udp_server.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write(udp_server_script)
    host2.cmd('python /tmp/udp_server.py &')

    # Send UDP packets from host1 to host2
    packets_sent = 0  # Counter for packets sent
    while packets_sent < 10:
        host1.cmd('echo "UDP Packet" | nc -u -w1 10.0.0.2 5000')  # Send UDP packets to host2 IP address
        packets_sent += 1  # Increment the counter for each packet sent

    # Retrieve the number of packets received from the output file
    output = host2.cmd('timeout 1 cat /tmp/output.txt')
    if output is None:
        output = ''
    else:
        output = output

    # Stop the UDP server on host2
    host2.cmd('kill %python')

    # Stop the network
    net.stop()

    # Print the number of packets sent and received
    print('Number of Packets Sent:', packets_sent)

    packets_received = len(re.findall(r'Received packet:.*', output))
    print('Number of Packets Received:', packets_received)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    simulate_packet_loss()
```

Comment: This isn't even valid Python code; it would fail with `NameError: name '_name_' is not defined. Did you mean: '__name__'?`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you haven't configured an OVS controller, so your switch never passes any packets. The simplest solution is to explicitly use the `OVSBridge` class for switches, which is a standalone switch that passes all packets:

```
def simulate_packet_loss():
    # Create Mininet network
    net = Mininet(switch=OVSBridge)

    [...]
```

With this change, your code runs and is able to successfully pass packets between the two hosts:

```
$ sudo python simulate_packet_loss.py
Number of Packets Sent: 10
Number of Packets Received: 10
```